# How to properly duplicate a variable so that the value of the copy changes when the original variable changes it's value

Tags: python

probably a silly question by I can't figure it out myself so here it goes.
I'm trying to duplicate a variable so that when the original variable changes it's value, the copy changes as well.
I've tried it this way but it's clearly not working:

```
x = 10
y = x
x = 20
y
10
```

how do I make y to equal 20 only by changing x?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of the object, and whether the object is mutable or immutable. Since you values are integers, you can't. It would work if, for example, they were lists.